# FloatingActionButton does not show up on app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I want to create a simple layout in Android like that of Gmail Inbox. A list of items and a FloatingActionButton to add a new item. In the design tab of Android Studio, the button shows up. However, when I launch the app in emulator, the button does not show up. I am using a recyclerview for displaying items. The items get displayed correctly.

Fragment code

```
    <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/question_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tl.dialog"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}



 dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    }
```

Comment: You could use [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html) at runtime to check if the FAB is part of the emulator/ device screen

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about this feature. I am not able to see the FAB in layout inspector. Actually, the inspector only shows recyclerview inside the ViewPager. It does not mention the framelayout as well. Something terrible going on here?

Comment: "Shows" like in the picture or also "shows" in the View hierarchy list on the left side? The FrameLayout may have been merged with the ViewPager tab, but let's concentrate on the missing FAB. If it's in the list but not on the screen then may be below the lower screen edge.

Comment: "Shows" as in view hierarchy. Both Framelayout and FAB missing in view hierarchy as well as sceen.

Comment: That's bad. In this case you should post enough code to reproduce your error (so we can easily set up a small sample).

Comment: Only code remaining is the recyclerview adapter. Rest everything I have shared. I know the reference to the files are correct because if i make any changes in the recycler view design, they get reflected.

Comment: "Rest everything I have shared" - well, you did not post any Java (or Kotlin) code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168252/discussion-between-adi-and-0x0nosugar).

Comment: Good, there's finally enough code so I can reproduce the error. Which gives me the opportunity to make sure I really have a solution before posting an answer. Interesting problem. I'll get back to you as soon as I find out anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the `RecyclerView` from `onCreateView()` not the root `View`. (I suppose this happened because in some earlier version you only had a `RecyclerView` inside the `Fragment`)

So all you have to change is the last line of `onCreateView()`, instead of `return recycler;` it should be

```
return mView;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Not sure how long would it have took for me to figure out. Inheritance can be a tough nut sometimes. Any suggestions around best practices on how to avoid such problems in future?

Comment: Mainly one suggestion: use your own coding conventions, like "always name the inflated View the same, e.g. 'root'." This way, your last statement will of course be "return root;" And maybe (may not apply here) run tests more often so harmful changes will surface earlier

Comment: BTW I found out what was wrong when I used the problem Fragment standalone in an otherwise empty Activity and got an Exception because the Fragment's View already seemed to have a parent. Suddenly the last line in onCreateView() was a very important line to look at, and then everything made sense.